# Wikipedia censorship breaks after accessing Wikimedia

Tags: censorship

I live in Turkey, and Wikipedia is blocked for some stupid reason!

But I've noticed that if I open "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" which is not censored, I can then access Wikipedia as if it is not blocked at all, provided that I'm using the same browser.

Could anyone please explain what's happening here?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that was it, loading Wikimedia will create 2 cookies, namely CP: "H2" and GeoIP: "TR:77:Yalova:40.66:29.28:v4".
Loading Wikipedia without first loading Wikimedia will fail to generate those, but if Wikimedia was loaded, then Wikipedia will use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this again with firebug, check the cookies created on your computer when you view wikimedia, it should be there a cookie that lets you pass on the censorship. You'll have to do the dirty job, cause outside of Turkey we can't test such...

Comment: Is there a way to make the cookies permanent? so they are used every time?

Comment: Yes mate, set it read only! ;)

Comment: How would that work? The site uses SSL, so a MITM can't check cookies.

Comment: @Arminius I'm sorry sir but I didn't get the point of your comment.

Comment: How would setting a cookie let you circumvent censorship in the first place? Even if that did work, how would the government verify these cookies on an encrypted connection?

Comment: I don't know, but: given the question, given it's true (I view this and is censored, but if I view that and then come back to this, this works). With the given info, it can only be a cookie, or the inquirer didn't provide valid infos.

Comment: I can assure you it is true, I've been accessing Wikipedia using this method for over a week, and it really makes me think how it's even working.

Comment: @Mo3tasm I don't doubt your observation at all. I'm just saying that this answer doesn't currently provide a plausible explanation. A government would block IPs, DNS, etc. I find it very unlikely that their censoring is based on cookies.

Comment: I agree with you that my answer didn't provide an explanation, but with the given details it MUST be a cookie. I don't know how Turkish gov does it's censorship, nor I know how and if would Wikipedia do to circumvent censorships. Of course they are not blocking dns nor ips. I look forward like you for a better explanation for me, you, @Mo3tasm and for the whole community.